# I want to give this ribbon kind of background to one of my illustration. How Do I achieve that?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

[image]

I want to give this ribbon effect to a graphic. But I don't know how do I achieve it. 
Do I need to make every rectangle individually? Or there is any method to save time?

Comment: The fastest way to put the above into your background is to pay the $10 for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an automated, one-click process, but it doesn't take long once you get the hang of it...

- Create one object of each colour/shape that you require.
- Duplicate these objects until you have the desired number of copies.
- Go to `Object > Transform > Transform Each...`
- Turn on the 'Preview' and 'Random' check boxes.
- Play with the Scale, Move & Rotate sliders until you like what you see.
- Redistribute the randomised objects as required.